# C++11 - Moving fundamental data types in constructor?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

I'm looking into move semantics from C++11 and I'm curious how to move fundamental types like boolean, integer float etc. in the constructor. Also the compound types like std::string.

Take the following class for example:

```
class Test
{
public:
    // Default.
    Test()
        : m_Name("default"), m_Tested(true), m_Times(1), m_Grade('B')
    {
        // Starting up...
    }
    Test(const Test& other)
        : m_Name(other.m_Name), m_Times(other.m_Times)
        , m_Grade(other.m_Grade), m_Tested(other.m_Tested)
    {
        // Duplicating...
    }
    Test(Test&& other)
        : m_Name(std::move(other.m_Name)) // Is this correct?
    {
        // Moving...
        m_Tested = other.m_Tested; // I want to move not copy.
        m_Times = other.m_Times; // I want to move not copy.
        m_Grade = other.m_Grade; // I want to move not copy.
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        // Shutting down....
    }

private:
    std::string     m_Name;
    bool            m_Tested;
    int             m_Times;
    char            m_Grade;
};
```

How do I move (not copy) m_Tested, m_Times, m_Grade. And is m_Name moved correctly? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialization and assignment of a primitive from a prvalue or xvalue primitive has exactly the same effect as initialization or assignment from a lvalue primitive; the value is copied and the source object is unaffected.

In other words, you can use `std::move` but it won't make any difference.

If you want to change the value of the source object (to `0`, say) you'll have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct. Except simple data types like bool, int, char are only copied. The point of "moving" a string is that it has a buffer that it normally has to copy when constructing a new object, however when moving the old buffer is used (copying the pointer and not the contents of the buffer).

```
Test(Test&& other)
    : m_Name(std::move(other.m_Name)), m_Times(other.m_Times)
    , m_Grade(other.m_Grade), m_Tested(other.m_Tested)
{}
```